# Opening Office 2013 files in Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, file-corruption, file-format

I have Office 2010 and I need to look at an Excel 2013 file. 
How do I do this? 
Excel 2010 tells me it is a corrupt file and cannot open it. 
Is there a technique that will allow me to view newer spreadsheets in older versions?

Comment: Open them in google docs if you have it available. Just open docs.google.com and import your file

Comment: The file formats did not change between Office 2010 and Office 2013; we have a mixed environment, and when either version has reported a file as being corrupt, it has truly been corrupt - never an issue of version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GoogleDocs. Upload it and open it, then save it as usual.

Is the file in good condition? Like, Are you really sure that the file is not corrupt?

Comment: If you require clarification, you should submit your questions, as a comment not part of your answer. Comments and your own questions to clarify the question should never be submitted as an answer.

Comment: I delivered what the user asked, and app that does what is needed to do. Then asked is the file is in good condition, why is this asking for clarification?

Comment: *Yes, GoogleDocs. Upload it and open it, then save it as usual.  Is the file in good condition? Like, Are you really sure that the file is not corrupt?*. Who are these questions directed towards if not the author to clarify their question?